# $X$ is Hausdorff if for any $a,b\in X$, there is a continuous $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=1$

Tags: general-topology

If the topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$ has the property that for every distinct pair of points $a, b \in X $ there is a continuous function $f_{a,b}$ from $X$ to $\mathbb R $ (with the usual topology) such that $$f_{a,b}(a)=0\;;\;f_{a,b}(b)=1$$ How can it be shown that $(X, \mathcal T)$ is a Hausdorff space?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** There are open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ separating $0$ and $1$, e.g. $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})$.

Comment: Cannot we generalize this to $f_{a,b}:X\to Y$ where $Y$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: Indeed we can generalize it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What could you say of the inverse image under $f$ of the sets $(-1/2,1/2)$ and $(3/4,5/4)$?

Comment: I should probably mention I have absolutely no idea how to approach this.

Comment: @jorgea You need to show that given $a\ne b$ in $X$, there are disjoint open sets $O_a$ and $O_b$ in $X$ containing $a$ and $b$ respectively. To do this, fix $a\ne b$ and consider the sets $f_{a,b}^{-1}((-1/2,1/2))$ and  $f_{a,b}^{-1}((3/4,5/4))$. Use the facts that Ittay mentions in his answer to show these sets are open in $X$ and disjoint.  You also need to verify that $a$ is in one of these sets and $b$ in the other.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1) The inverse image under a continuous mappings of an open set is an open set.

2) There exist disjoint open sets in $\mathbb R$, one containing $0$ but not $1$, and one containing $1$ but not $0$.

3) The inverse image of disjoint sets is disjoint.